# How do I delete something from a server using POST?

Tags: java-me

I'm new to J2ME. How do I delete something from a server using the POST method? Samples would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DELETE method instead

I would recommend [Apache HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpDelete.html).
Example

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/resource");
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setRequestProperty(
    "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
httpCon.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
httpCon.connect();
```